# Django Admin crash when trying to delete an object

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a problem where Django Admin (I run Django 1.3) crashes whenever I try to delete an object and the admin tries to display what child objects will be affected by the action. I'm able to delete the object fine in the terminal. This is the traceback:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response 
response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 307, in wrapper 
return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 93, in _wrapped_view 
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 79, in _wrapped_view_func 
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 197, in inner 
return view(request, *args, **kwargs) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 28, in _wrapper 
return bound_func(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 93, in _wrapped_view 
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 24, in bound_func 
return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 217, in inner 
res = func(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1201, in delete_view 
[obj], opts, request.user, self.admin_site, using) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py", line 104, in get_deleted_objects 
to_delete = collector.nested(format_callback) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py", line 158, in nested 
roots.extend(self._nested(root, seen, format_callback)) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py", line 141, in _nested 
children.extend(self._nested(child, seen, format_callback)) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py", line 141, in _nested 
children.extend(self._nested(child, seen, format_callback)) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py", line 136, in _nested 
if obj in seen: 
File "/test.py", line 371, in __eq__ 
return len(self.text) == len(other.text) 

AttributeError: 'ChildB' object has no attribute 'text'
```

This is what my models look like:

```
class Parent(models.Model):  pass

class ChildA(models.Model):

    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    text = models.CharField()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return len(self.text) == len(other.text)

class ChildB(models.Model):

    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    counter = models.IntegerField()
```

Why does Django Admin try to compare ChildA and ChildB? I've fixed the issue by adding a check to make sure it's the right type before comparing text length but wondering if anyone else have had this problem and if there is an issue with my structure here. Even more strange is that this doesn't happen for all parent objects.

Thanks, Mattias

Comment: Strange..!! your classes are not inheriting from models.

Comment: I presume that the page is trying to eliminate doubles from the list is trying to eliminate doubles from a list or so, or sorting a list with both types of instances, and that's leading to __eq__ being called. You should change __eq__ so that it works with any other object, not only ones that have a .text attribute.

Answer (score 0):

models are not correct

```
from django.db import models
class Parent(models.Model):
    pass

class ChildA(models.Model):

    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    text = models.CharField()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return len(self.text) == len(other.text)

class ChildB(models.Model):

    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    counter = models.IntegerField()
```

The function **eq** may lead this mistake, mark it and try again

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return len(self.text) == len(other.text)
```

Comment: I wrote pseudocode in my question just to illustrate the issue, my actual models doesn't look like this.